# Field calculator add sequential number to text field to populate a unique ID

Tags: arcmap, field-calculator

I am using arcmap 10.1 and working in a personal geodatabase. I am trying to add a sequential number to an [encounterID] field to populate a [sightingID] field. What code would i use?

For example I want to sequentially number my encounter ID's and populate the sighting id field as it appear in the sighting ID below and for multiple records.

Column 1

```
[encounterID]   
20170327.0301   
20170327.0301   
20170327.0301
```

Column 2

```
[sightingID]  
20170327.0301_1 
20170327.0301_2
20170327.0301_3
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Answer (score 7):

In the field calculator window, select Python Parser, check the Show Codeblock box.

Pre-logic script code:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
valueUsage = defaultdict(int)
def unique_id(inputfield):
    valueUsage[inputfield] += 1
    new_value = "{0}_{1}".format(inputfield, valueUsage[inputfield])
    return new_value
```

Expression:

```py
unique_id( !encounterID!)
```

[image]

The result in the attribute table

[image]

It doesn't matter the order in the table, it will number them sequentially based on the value in the `encounterID` field.

[image]

Comment: Fantastic This is exactly what I needed!!! Much appreciated!!

Comment: @Dawn If this has answered your question, please consider Voting and Accepting the answer.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)